# Hosting MVC 3 and My SQL as cheap like PHP and MySQL

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, hosting

I would like to develop an application that use ASP.Net MVC 3 and Razor with MySQL.

**I think both are open source and this will reduce my development cost, please correct me if i am wrong.**

Is development cost of ASP.Net MVC 3 + MySQL = PHP+MySQL ? or do i need a license for ASP.Net MVC 3 development?

Now i am looking for Hosting. Should be cheaper for MVC3 and MySQL and reliable.
Suggest me.

Comment: You do not need a license for ASP.Net MVC3 development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the development cost, but hosting cost will remain almost same in both the cases.

http://www.asp.net/hosting/home is a very good resource to find out Good windows host.